Create a complex directory structure in Azure Blob Store via Terraform
I am trying to create a complex, nested directory structure via Terraform using the azurem provider and the azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem and azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path resources. I also want to create ACLs using the ace block defined in the two resources. The depth and width of the directory structure is arbitrary.
The problem is that I need to create the path resources in order, otherwise ACL defaults aren't applied to child paths as expected.
Initially I defined an input variable that included a list of paths, and each entry contained the absolute path. e.g.:
/root/
/root/parent/
/root/parent2/
/root/parent/child

This works for creating the filesystem, but because terraform can't guarantee resource creation order (without implicit/explicit dependencies), the default ACLs aren't guaranteed to propagate to children as expected.
I tried constructing the full path name in the resource by looking for the parent resource (thus creating a dependency), but it reports a cyclical dependency when trying to build that graph (even though the dependencies are linear).
I can't use depends_on, because that seems to be used for resource blocks as opposed to resource instances.
I thought about creating a nested complex object where the dependencies are explicit, but it's not clear how I would then create individual resources based on that structure, since terraform doesn't really support recursive methods (from what i can tell).
I own the contract and the module, so I'm open to changing either side of the equation to simplify the solution. I can't imagine I'm the first person to run into this issue; how have others solved it?
Current input variable spec (I also tried with an explicit parent_path_name):
variable "filesystem_specs" {
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    owner_id           = optional(string)
    group_id           = optional(string)
    aces               = list(object({
      scope               = optional(string)
      type                = string
      object_id           = string
      permissions         = string
    }))

    paths              = list(object({
      path_name            = string
      aces                 = list(object({
        scope                = optional(string)
        type                 = string
        object_id            = string
        permissions          = string
      }))
    }))
  }))


You can use depends_on for individual resources is one way and the other was when we need complx structure you can use local-exec and define specific order manually as you requrired @cgrass


Creating a complex directory structure in Azure Blob Store via Terraform

One way is to reducing the problem into creating an ordered list of paths to which directs the dependencies in correct order sequence or otherwise of using nested paths directly, create a flattened list of paths with each path listing its explicit parent.
This will be used to generate Terraform resources with clear ordering dependencies.
configuration:
variable "filesystem_specs" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    paths = list(object({
      path_name = string
      aces = list(object({
        scope       = optional(string)
        type        = string
        id          = string
        permissions = string
      }))
    }))
  }))
}


and in the main.tf
locals {
  paths = flatten([
    for fs in var.filesystem_specs : [
      for path in fs.paths : {
        filesystem_name = fs.name
        path_name      = path.path_name
        level         = length(split("/", path.path_name))
        aces          = path.aces
      }
    ]
  ])

 
  paths_by_level = {
    for path in local.paths : path.level => path...
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "vkss-filesystem"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}


resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "directories" {
  for_each = {
    for path in local.paths : path.path_name => path
  }

  filesystem_name    = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.name
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  path              = each.key
  resource          = "directory"

  dynamic "ace" {
    for_each = each.value.aces
    content {
      scope       = lookup(ace.value, "scope", "default")
      type        = ace.value.type
      id          = ace.value.id
      permissions = ace.value.permissions
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example
  ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://shisho.dev/dojo/providers/azurerm/Storage/azurerm-storage-data-lake-gen2-path
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem?utm


It looks like this solution will create a directory structure of depth 2, but will not work for deeper structures. does it allow for the creation of /child in my example?



I want to be able to use default scopes in the ACE block, which will then be used to create access ACLs for future child objects (paths and files). Applying the ACE after the paths are created breaks that behavior, unless i reproduce the intelligence of determining parent defaults as well.


I have updated the solution as per the requirement to achieve level 3 and even level 4 complex directories please check and confrim @cgrass

I think that solves issue 1, but i think we have the same problem with issue 2; the ordering of the dir create isn't guaranteed, so default ACLs aren't necessarily applied as they should be. or maybe i'm misunderstanding some syntax?

I made changes in code please check once

Can you explain how the updated solution ensures ordering?
